# Custom chapter prefix text in KOMA-Script

Tags: koma-script

With `\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}`, I would like to replace the default text for the chapter prefix, so that it shows up in all the appropriate places: chapter heading, page headers, and preferable ToC. So, instead of "Chapter 1 Something," I would see "Assignment 1: Something."

I have looked in the KOMA-Script manual, particularly in the section on redefining or declaring sectioning commands, and couldn't figure out where the text is stored. I tried `\renewcommand\chapterformat{Assignment\enskip\thechapter:}` but it did not affect headers or ToC. I assume that there is a place where the string "chapter" is stored?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something}
chapter text

\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `\chapapp` is `Chapter` defined. You can change it with

```
\renewcommand{\chapapp}{Assignment}
```

So the complete code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoption{chapterprefix}{true}
\renewcommand{\chapapp}{Assignment} % <=================================


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something}
chapter text

\end{document}
```

gives you the result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [table 12.1 of the KOMA-Script guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#table.12.1) the term "Chapter" is stored in `\chaptername`. The table is part of the description of command [`\providecaptionname`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrbase.cmd.renewcaptionname), that can be used to define the language dependent term, e.g.,

```
\providecaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Assignment}
```

If the term should be changed for appendices too, you should additionally change `\appendixname`. Otherwise you would get "Appendix" after `\appendix`.

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\providecaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Assignment}
\providecaptionname{english}{\appendixname}{Assignment}% also change the prefix of appendices
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something}
chapter text

\appendix
\chapter{Something in the appendix}
appendix text
\end{document}
```

If you are using a language package like `babel` you should use `\renewcaptionname` instead of `\providecaptionname`:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\chaptername}{Assignment}
\renewcaptionname{english}{\appendixname}{Assignment}% also change the prefix of appendices
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Something}
chapter text

\appendix
\chapter{Something in the appendix}
appendix text
\end{document}
```